# How do I Export GridView to Excel?

Tags: c#

I am exporting a GridView to an Excel file, but when I open the file, first I get an error regarding the fact that the format type and extension don't match, and when I open it the whole page is brought into the Excel file, not just the grid view.

```
enter code here

  protected void ExportToExcel(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Response.Clear();
                Response.Buffer = true;
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=GridViewExport.xls");
                Response.Charset = "";
                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
                {
                    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

                    //To Export all pages
                    gridCustomer.AllowPaging = false;
                    //this.gridCustInfoBind(1);
                    gridCustAllInfoBind(1);

                    gridCustomer.HeaderRow.BackColor = Color.White;
                    foreach (TableCell cell in gridCustomer.HeaderRow.Cells)
                    {
                        cell.BackColor = gridCustomer.HeaderStyle.BackColor;
                    }
                    foreach (GridViewRow row in gridCustomer.Rows)
                    {
                        row.BackColor = Color.White;
                        foreach (TableCell cell in row.Cells)
                        {
                            if (row.RowIndex % 2 == 0)
                            {
                                cell.BackColor = gridCustomer.AlternatingRowStyle.BackColor;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                cell.BackColor = gridCustomer.RowStyle.BackColor;
                            }
                            cell.CssClass = "textmode";
                        }
                    }

                    gridCustomer.RenderControl(hw);

                    //style to format numbers to string
                    string style = @"<style> .textmode { } </style>";
                    Response.Write(style);
                    Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
                    Response.Flush();
                    Response.End();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Exception Message: " + ex.Message.Replace("'", "").Replace("\"", "") + "');", true);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Because the generated file content is .html not .xls

Comment: How to convert it into .xls,can you modify my code.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on doodlereport nuget package, I think it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

the below code will convert your datatable to Excel, so you can use it instead:

```
 public void CreateExcel(DataTable dt, string path)
    {

        try
        {
            if (File.Exists(path))
                File.Delete(path);

            FileInfo newFile = new FileInfo(path);
            using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage(newFile))
            {
                //Create the worksheet
                ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Query Result");

                //Load the datatable into the sheet, starting from cell A1. Print the column names on row 1
                //ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dt, true);
                //ws.Cells["A1"].AutoFitColumns();

                int columnNumber = 0;
                foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
                {
                    columnNumber++;
                    ws.Cells[1, columnNumber].Value = dc.ColumnName;
                }

                //Adding data of each row.
                int rowNumber = 0;
                foreach (DataRow rw in dt.Rows)
                {
                    rowNumber++;

                    columnNumber = 0;
                    foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
                    {
                        columnNumber++;
                        //Formating columns based on data types
                        if (rw[dc.ColumnName].GetType().ToString() == "System.Int32" || rw[dc.ColumnName].GetType().ToString() == "System.Double")
                            ws.Cells[rowNumber + 1, columnNumber].Style.Numberformat.Format = "0";
                        else if (rw[dc.ColumnName].GetType().ToString() == "System.DateTime")
                            ws.Cells[rowNumber + 1, columnNumber].Style.Numberformat.Format = "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss";
                        else if (rw[dc.ColumnName].GetType().ToString() == "System.Decimal")
                            ws.Cells[rowNumber + 1, columnNumber].Style.Numberformat.Format = "0.00";

                        ws.Cells[rowNumber + 1, columnNumber].Value = rw[dc.ColumnName];
                    }
                }


                //Format the header for columns
                using (ExcelRange rng = ws.Cells["A1:Z1"])
                {
                    rng.Style.Font.Bold = true;

                }

                //Format Cells 
                using (ExcelRange col = ws.Cells[2, 1, dt.Rows.Count + 1, dt.Columns.Count + 1])
                {
                    col.Style.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Right;
                    col.Style.VerticalAlignment = ExcelVerticalAlignment.Center;
                    col.AutoFitColumns();
                }

                //Saving the excel sheet
                pck.Save();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }



    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Linq2Excel. Its an opensource tool and available on Nuget.

https://github.com/paulyoder/LinqToExcel